# Optimal way to find intersection in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have User and Chat model in Laravel app. User can be member in many chats so I have many-to-many relation between chats and users - `belongsToMany` is used.

Let's say I know few user IDs and I want to retrieve all **common chats** (chats where they are members at the same time, e.g., group chats where **all** the users with the given IDs are grouped in). How this query should be build using Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

The most optimal way would be to do a join:

```php
Chat::join('chat_user', 'chat_id', 'chats.id')
   ->whereIn('chat_user.user_id',$listOfUserIds)
   ->selectRaw('chat_user.chat_id, COUNT(1) as users_count')
   ->groupBy('chat_user.chat_id')
   ->having('users_count','=', count($listOfUserIds));
```

This is optimal because it only joins the pivot.

The elegant way to do this though is to use `whereHas` with the "cardinality" parameters, i.e., find all chats which those users are involved in as long as all of them are involved.

```
Chat::whereHas('user', function ($q) {
    return $q->whereIn('id', $listOfUserIds);
}, '=', count($listOfUserIds));
```

this still only does one query but joins the pivot and the users table.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that I am getting all chats where listed users are members, but not all chats where they are members same time. Maybe my question was inaccurate

Comment: Can you share more details on your structure? As I understand it you mean that you want chats where all members are participating at the same time? (i.e. like in a group chat?)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I have users, chats tables and user_chats table with user_id and chat_id fields

Comment: Try the update. `whereIn` behaves like an `OR` but doing `where([...])` with an array of conditions should behave like an `AND`

Comment: I added missing parentheses and ; in both queries and updated them to match table names - but both fails

Comment: Sorry was a bit hasty. Here's the first version but ensuring the number of matching users found should all the ones we are looking for. Hopefully this version works

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    $membersWithChats = Member::whereIn('id', $listOfIDs)->with('chats')->get();
```